# Работа с массивами строк в C

Tags: c, массивы, строки, сравнение

Я пишу программу, в которой вводятся несколько строк, причем вводить их надо именно в массив. Ввод происходит нормально, однако потом мне надо работать с отдельными символами строк массива. Как сравнить символ одиночной строки с символом строки из массива? (Я пробовал str[0] == str[i][0], но так не работает)

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? И определитесь `str[0] == str[i][0]` что такое str - массив или строка. И какая строка у Вас? `char*`?

Comment: Не работает  - значит некорректно сравнивает; у меня первая строка char s1[], а вторая char s2[][]; мне надо сравнить последний элемент s1 с первым элементом i-ой строки массива s2

Answer (score 1):

> у меня первая строка char s1[], а вторая char s2[][]; мне надо сравнить последний элемент s1 с первым элементом i-ой строки массива s2

Как-то так

```
if (s1[strlen(s1) - 1] == s2[i][0])
```